# How to use to_date in gemfire?

Tags: gemfire, geode

I am trying to query by date into my gemfire region.  Can anybody please help with how the to_date should be formatted to make a date query into my gemfire region.

I have a date formatted `'MM/dd/yyyy'` and then I want to run a query that selects if the date equals the same time.

> select * from /myRegion where regionDate = inputDate;

I have review the documentation and see that there is a to_date function, and have tried the following

> select *  from /myRegion where regionDate = to_date('07/01/2015',
>   'MM/dd/yyyy)

```
Caused by: line 1:75: unexpected token: 07
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.inExpr(OQLParser.java:2135)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.multiplicativeExpr(OQLParser.java:2056)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.additiveExpr(OQLParser.java:1983)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.relationalExpr(OQLParser.java:1874)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.equalityExpr(OQLParser.java:1829)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.andthenExpr(OQLParser.java:1685)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.quantifierExpr(OQLParser.java:1652)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.andExpr(OQLParser.java:1569)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.orelseExpr(OQLParser.java:1531)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.orExpr(OQLParser.java:1492)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.castExpr(OQLParser.java:1474)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.expr(OQLParser.java:1145)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.whereClause(OQLParser.java:1188)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.selectExpr(OQLParser.java:1089)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.query(OQLParser.java:187)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.parse.OQLParser.queryProgram(OQLParser.java:103)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.query.internal.QCompiler.compileQuery(QCompiler.java:53)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote (') in you OQL syntax after the date format pattern...

```
select * from /myRegion where regionDate = to_date('07/01/2015', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks, noticed this when doing some more testing.